# not putting (var i = 0) causes infinite loop

Tags: javascript, recursion, infinite-loop

In my following code if I do not put (var i = 0...) in the for loop I got an infinite loop.

```
function steamrollArray(arr) {
 var newArr = [];
 for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (Array.isArray(arr[i])) {
    newArr = newArr.concat(steamrollArray(arr[i]));
  } else {
    newArr.push(arr[i]);
  }
 }
 return newArr;
}

steamrollArray([1, [], [3, [[4]]]]);
```

Can anyone please explain why ?

Comment: Simillar [**problem**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44731704/javascript-for-loop-fori-0-i-3-i-terminates-too-early-without-using). In this case the loop terminates early rather than loop infinitly (but both problems are the same).

Comment: global variables ftw! Always define your variables.

Comment: thanks everyone for the quick responses. I shall always declare my variables then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you don't declare a variable with the `var` keyword inside function it's counts as a global variable.

I assume that in your `steamrollArray` function you also use `i` and change is value, so it pass the `arr.length` when it return from the function and now it's bigger then `arr.length` and the loop never ends.

always declare variabled with `var` in functions, it also a good pratice to avoid gloval variabled

Comment: No need to assume anything...all the code is right there in question

Comment: or rather with `let` if you don't need the variable outside of the loop. This helps with memory

Comment: @charlietfl You right, I didn't notice that is the same function